# Make Eclipse generate C++ executable file

Tags: c++, eclipse, ide, compilation, binary

Using latest MinGW and C++ Eclipse.

If I create an "Executable Hello World" project, build it and run it, everything works as expected.

If I create an "Executable Empty Project", then create a main.cpp file, build and run, I get the error message "Launch failed. Binary not found."

How can I make empty project generate binary files? I looked everywhere in the project properties but I must have missed it.

Comment: Did you set the build artifact ot be an executable?

Comment: @JakubZaverka Yes, it is set that way

Comment: Try cleaning the project, then explicitly build the project. Watch the output if there are some errors. If the build is successful, you should get a Debug folder in the project folder with the executable. Then click on the project and press the Run button.

Comment: @JakubZaverka Done. In the Debug/Release folders I only get a "main.o" file, no executable files. The same error appears when I try to Run the project.

Comment: Did you get the "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" message in the build console?

Comment: @JakubZaverka It says "Build Finished." This is the pastebin of the build log http://pastebin.com/06r2kiBx

Comment: _main.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status_ Here is your problem.

Comment: @JakubZaverka I see - but the Hello World project generates .o files too. How can I fix that? I have no idea

Comment: You can compare the setting in these two projects and see where they differ.

Comment: http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,6108.msg46765.html this may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the solution was this:

select your project and goto "project"-menu/properties (on mac).

c/c++ Build/Settings.

Binary parsers. now tick the one that suits your system (elf for linux, mach 64 for mac, pe for windows etc). the default is always elf and it reverts to it after every project, at least for me.

Answer (score 2):

On Eclipse Kepler (c++) with standard settings I today discovered that the error parser that creates the output in the "Problem" tab failed

In the console there was an compile error from gcc, but it didn't show in the Problem tab, which is the one I look in the most. It was a type conversion error, very typical and nothing exotic, definitely something that should be included as an error.

Hope it helps someone.