# Eclipse executable arch type

Tags: c++, macos, eclipse-cdt

I faced with issue when I trying to create executable file for linux system on my mac using `Eclipse` and c++ project.

I can prepare executable, but for arch `x86_64`

`$ file <fileName>: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64`

Sample executable that works fine on linux system before has `ELF 32-bit LSB executable`:

`$ file <fileName_original>: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0, with debug_info, not stripped`

As result when I trying to run debug mode within `Eclipse`

> root@:~# gdbserver  :2345 /home/; exit Process
>   /home/ created; pid = 1578 
>   Cannot exec /home/: Exec format
>   error.
>
> Child exited with status 127 
>   No program to debug.  GDBserver exiting

So the problem is definitely in incorrect arch type.

I saw a lot of similar questions (mostly for windows platform like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936792/make-eclipse-generate-c-executable-file) or [this](https://forum.redpitaya.com/viewtopic.php?t=1684) - all of them recommend to change Binary parser in proj settings - I have tested all of them - result same, so this solution is not working for me

So my question - is there is a way to change arch type for executable generated within `Eclipse` on macOS?

Note: 
- `Eclipse` info:

> Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
>
> Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0)
>   Build id: 20200313-1211

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found instruction how to do so (thanks to advice).

U need to:

- Install and setup `SFTP` on `LinkIt Smart 7688` development board with opkg.
- Install `Eclipse C/C++ GCC Cross Compiler Support` and `Remote System explorer End-User Runtime`. Newer versions of `Eclipse` may have these packages installed
  already.
- Create an `Eclipse C/C++ Cross GCC` project.
- Setup `STAGING_DIR` environment variable, tool command prefix, tool path and GDB tool path in the project settings.
- Build and setup sign-in password to `LinkIt Smart 7688` development board. The IDE will automatically build, upload and execute the resulting binary.

Complete instruction is [here](https://docs.labs.mediatek.com/resource/linkit-smart-7688/en/tutorials/c-c++-programming/building-and-debugging-c-c++-programs-with-eclipse-ide).

Also, on macOS u may also needs to install `gdb` and prepare eclipse for debug(remote debug), to do so - just follow [another instruction](https://www.thomasvitale.com/how-to-setup-gdb-and-eclipse-to-debug-c-files-on-macos-sierra/).